# MySQL join to return count(report) from all places, even where the number is zero

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
countries: province, country, lat, lng

reports: title, province, country, lat, lng
```

There are thousands of province, country combinations that have no reports, but I have received a request to print out all data from every province, even if there is no report associated with those provinces, which I would like MySQL to return 0.

I have given the Excel guy,

```
SELECT province, country, lat, lng, COUNT(report)
FROM reports
GROUP BY lat,lng
```

Obviously this only gives places that have hits associated with them. However, he said he needs the places that contain 0. I know this must be some sort of 'join' function, but I can't figure out how to do this efficiently.

Comment: What are the primary keys for your tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.province, c.country, c.lat, c.lng, COUNT(r.title)
    FROM countries c
        LEFT JOIN reports r
            ON c.province = r.province
                AND c.country = r.country
                AND c.lat = r.lat
                AND c.lng = r.lng
    GROUP BY c.province, c.country, c.lat, c.lng
```